# Getting and removing a part of a string by first and last occurance of character

Tags: c#

I have a string like this:

```
{something:something}Some data will be here
```

Heres how its setup:

```
{username:password}data
```

How can I get the {username:password} part and remove it from the full string? I need to check the username and password then send the data (everything after {something:something}) to the user.

Preferably I would like to get the username:password without the {} so I can just split by :

Comment: Try using regex

Comment: What have you tried so far? what have you googled?

Comment: I can't find anything on google..

Comment: @Keriosk: how are you searching? If you use words like "find" and "remove" or "replace" with "string" and the language (C#) in Google, you should surely find plenty of resources. At the very least, look at the MSDN entry for the `String` class, which has a lot of obviously named methods. I hate to say RTFM, but in this case, I think at least taking a cursory look at what's readily available would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex solution :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "{something:something}Some data will be here";

            string pattern = @"\{(?'username'[^:]+):(?'password'[^\}]+)\}(?'data'.*)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input,pattern);

            Console.WriteLine("Username : '{0}', Password : '{1}', Data : '{2}'",
                match.Groups["username"].Value, match.Groups["password"].Value, match.Groups["data"].Value);
           Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first use `substring` and `index of` to remove the unwanted characters.

```
string input = {username:password}data
input = input.Substring(input.IndexOf("}") +1);   //data
```

This will give you the data part assuming } occurs only once.

Comment: I don't think that's how that works anyways, `input.Substring(input.IndexOf("}"));` will return `}data` Substring returns the text starting at your index, or between two indexes if you supply a start and end.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I fixed it now. Was a mistake earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public int IndexOfNth(string str, string value, int nth)
        {
            int offset = str.IndexOf(value);
            for (int i = 0; i < nth; i++)
            {
                if (offset == -1) return -1;
                offset = str.IndexOf(value, offset + 1);
            }
            return offset;
        }
```

this method returns the index of the value you want to find ex)@ fron the `str` and of the `nth` position ex)2 will return the 3rd occurance of @ in ***chris@so@sk@***

this can be used to substring `Strings`

maybe this will work:

```
string x= "{username:password}data";
string username = x.substring(1,IndexoOfNth(x,":",0)-1);
```